# d3 brush and clipPath: Main chart outside bounds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to do a bar chart with a brush component (based on https://bl.ocks.org/SevenChan07/495cd567e0ede0deeb14bb3599dce685) and using the enter-merge-exit pattern but I cant make the brush working properly. When I move the brush the chart goes beyond its bounds. I has probably to do with clipping but I dont know how to fix it.

```
var defs = focus.append('defs');

// use clipPath
defs.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'my-clip-path')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb0jv6mf/50/) and below is a snippet:

```js
let barData = []
for(let i = 0;i < 100; i++){
  barData.push({
    Prob: Math.random()*10,
    labels: 'test' + i
  })
}

barchart(barData)
    
    
function barchart(data) {

    var ordinals = data.map(function (d) {
        return d.labels;
    });


    var svg = d3.select("#myPlot").select("svg");
    var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 0.3 * svg.attr("height"),
            left: 40
        },
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        margin2 = {
            top: 20 + margin.top + height,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 40
        },
        height2 = height / 5;

    // the scale
    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).nice(),
        x2: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).nice(),
        y: d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).nice(),
        y2: d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]).nice()
    };

    let xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(-1, ordinals.length)).range([0, width])

    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => ordinals[d]),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y)
    };

    var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
        .on("brush", brushed)


    var focus = svg.select('.focus')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    focus.select(".axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height +")");

    var context = svg.select('.context')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


    var defs = focus.append('defs');

    // use clipPath
    defs.append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'my-clip-path')
        .append('rect')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    function updateScales(data) {
        scale.x.domain([-1, ordinals.length])
        scale.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.Prob)])
        scale.x2.domain(scale.x.domain())
        scale.y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.Prob)])
    }


    svg.call(renderPlot, data)

    function renderPlot(selection, data) {
        updateScales(data);

        selection.select(".context")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")")
            .select('.brush')
            .call(brush)
            .call(brush.move, scale.x.range())

        selection.select(".axis2")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 +")");

        selection.select(".focus").select(".axis").call(axis.x);
        selection.select(".focus").select(".axis.axis--y").call(axis.y);

        selection
            .call(renderPoints, data);
    }


    function renderPoints(selection, data) {
        
        var points = selection.select('.focus')
           .selectAll('.bar').data(data);

        var newPoints = points.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => {
                return scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height - scale.y(d.Prob)
            });

        points.merge(newPoints)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => {
                return scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height - scale.y(d.Prob)
            });

        points.exit()
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .remove();


        var sPoints = selection.select('.context').selectAll('.bar').data(data);

        var newsPoints = sPoints.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x2(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => scale.y2(d.Prob))
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height2 - scale.y2(d.Prob)
            });

        sPoints.merge(newsPoints)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x2(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => scale.y2(d.Prob))
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height2 - scale.y2(d.Prob)
            });

        sPoints.exit()
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .remove();



    }


    function brushed() {
        var s = d3.event.selection || scale.x2.range()
        scale.x.domain(s.map(scale.x2.invert, scale.x2))
        focus.select('.axis').call(axis.x)
        focus.selectAll('.bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bar { fill: steelblue; }
    </style>

<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class='chart span4' id='myPlot'>
    <svg width="700" height="500">
      <g class="focus">
        <g class="axis"></g>
        <g class="axis axis--y"></g>
      </g>
      <g class="context">
        <g class="axis2"></g>
        <g class="brush"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it, you just need to apply the clip path to something. We can easily do this with your bars (you could use a `g` containing *only* the bars too):

```
var newPoints = points.enter().append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .....  // other attributes
   .attr("clip-path","url(#my-clip-path)");
```

We only need to do it on enter, as the clip path doesn't need to be updated (we aren't changing it). Here's a snippet below:

```js
let barData = []
for(let i = 0;i < 100; i++){
  barData.push({
    Prob: Math.random()*10,
    labels: 'test' + i
  })
}

barchart(barData)
    
    
function barchart(data) {

    var ordinals = data.map(function (d) {
        return d.labels;
    });


    var svg = d3.select("#myPlot").select("svg");
    var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 0.3 * svg.attr("height"),
            left: 40
        },
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        margin2 = {
            top: 20 + margin.top + height,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 40
        },
        height2 = height / 5;

    // the scale
    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).nice(),
        x2: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).nice(),
        y: d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).nice(),
        y2: d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]).nice()
    };

    let xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(-1, ordinals.length)).range([0, width])

    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => ordinals[d]),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y)
    };

    var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
        .on("brush", brushed)


    var focus = svg.select('.focus')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    focus.select(".axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height +")");

    var context = svg.select('.context')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


    var defs = focus.append('defs');

    // use clipPath
    defs.append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'my-clip-path')
        .append('rect')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    function updateScales(data) {
        scale.x.domain([-1, ordinals.length])
        scale.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.Prob)])
        scale.x2.domain(scale.x.domain())
        scale.y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.Prob)])
    }


    svg.call(renderPlot, data)

    function renderPlot(selection, data) {
        updateScales(data);

        selection.select(".context")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")")
            .select('.brush')
            .call(brush)
            .call(brush.move, scale.x.range())

        selection.select(".axis2")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 +")");

        selection.select(".focus").select(".axis").call(axis.x);
        selection.select(".focus").select(".axis.axis--y").call(axis.y);

        selection
            .call(renderPoints, data);
    }


    function renderPoints(selection, data) {
        
        var points = selection.select('.focus')
           .selectAll('.bar').data(data);

        var newPoints = points.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => {
                return scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height - scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            .attr("clip-path","url(#my-clip-path)");

        points.merge(newPoints)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => {
                return scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height - scale.y(d.Prob)
            })
            

        points.exit()
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .remove();


        var sPoints = selection.select('.context').selectAll('.bar').data(data);

        var newsPoints = sPoints.enter().append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x2(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => scale.y2(d.Prob))
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height2 - scale.y2(d.Prob)
            });

        sPoints.merge(newsPoints)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x2(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => scale.y2(d.Prob))
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9)
            .attr('height', d => {
                return height2 - scale.y2(d.Prob)
            });

        sPoints.exit()
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .remove();



    }


    function brushed() {
        var s = d3.event.selection || scale.x2.range()
        scale.x.domain(s.map(scale.x2.invert, scale.x2))
        focus.select('.axis').call(axis.x)
        focus.selectAll('.bar')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                return scale.x(i) - xBand.bandwidth() * 0.9 / 2
            })
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bar { fill: steelblue; }
    </style>

<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class='chart span4' id='myPlot'>
    <svg width="700" height="500">
      <g class="focus">
        <g class="axis"></g>
        <g class="axis axis--y"></g>
      </g>
      <g class="context">
        <g class="axis2"></g>
        <g class="brush"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks Andrew. It works like a charm. I spent hours looking to do this! In fact I was trying to add the clip-path attr at the very beginning of the enter-update-exit pattern, right before we bind the data. Is there a way to define the rect of the clipPath outside the js code and inside the html please? Hence the code in the js would only grab and manipulate it and not append it, since it already exists

Comment: Sure, in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9cr8Lm1/) I've created the clip path in the DOM using HTML and then select the rectangle in the clip path and adjust the width/height to match the dimensions of the plot area (if you knew these before hand you could specify them in the HTML as well, removing the need to have d3 modify the clip path at all).

Comment: Thanks a million for your help! Thats really great. I tried something really close to this, i was actually putting the clipPath and the rect inside the focus group but for some reason I couldnt grab it from the js code. The reason I wanted this is that this barchart is going to be updated when the user clicks points on a scatter plot. The barchart will show info related to clicked point. If the clipPath and other elements are appended from js then they will be created each time the barchart js script is parsed (ie on each mouseclick). Now only one of these element show up.