# Unable to Zoom in Stacked Bar Chart d3.js V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I trying to build a stacked barchart with brush and zoom using d3.js v4.I was able to render the chart as well as the brush. However, when trying to zoom in only the axis changes and actual graph remains the same. I am attaching the snippet here.

Reference : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Thanks for your help in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   
    .zoom {
      cursor: move;
      fill: none;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
       
    .axis {
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
      stroke: #888;
      font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis > path {
      stroke: #888;
    }

</style>


<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    margin2 = {top: 230, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#a54300","#ec983d", "#ecc43d", "#f9ec86","#cbe989"]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Udayshan07/320ea33bacc3e04f9bd77538007527a0/raw/06e65434349e63ed6cf85c4d3e9cb383e888010c/sp500.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Week_Num = parseTime(d.Week_Num);
  });

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Week_Num; });
  var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; }));
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
  var data = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);

  x.domain([xMin, new Date()]);
  y.domain([0, yMax]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain())
  z.domain(keys);
 
  var messages = focus.append("g");
    messages.selectAll("message")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })   
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Week_Num); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .attr("width", 15)
     .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 5;
            var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 5;
            tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
            tooltip.select("text").text(d[1]-d[0]);
        });

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis.ticks(10))
      .selectAll("text") 
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
 
  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2)
      .selectAll("text") 
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());

  
});

function brushed() {
    //console.log('Brush 1');
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
   // console.log('Brush 2');
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.selectAll(".message")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Week_Num); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { colsole.log("Brush" + y(d[1])); return  y(d[1]); });
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  //  console.log('Zoom 1');
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; 
  // ignore zoom-by-brush
//    console.log('Zoom 2');
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.selectAll(".message")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Week_Num); })
        .attr("y", function(d) {  colsole.log("Zoom" + y(d[1])); return  y(d[1]);});
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}

var tooltip = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");
      
  tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);

  tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the question you have two primary issues:

1. You are not selecting anything on zoom/drag events:

In the zoomed/drag functions:

```
 focus.selectAll(".message")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Week_Num); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { colsole.log("Brush" + y(d[1])); return  y(d[1]); });
```

No items have the class `message` so this is an empty selection - which is why the command `colsole.log` doesn't trip an error, it's never run. You could just select all `rect`s in the focus selection instead (or give each rect the message class). *Also, you don't need to re-position the y value,  you aren't rescaling the y value, so it can stay the same, I've removed it in my snippet below*

Once that is changed, we run into problem 2.

2. You've changed the value you are passing the x scale. When you initially give an x attribute to each `rect` you use: `x(d.data.Week_Num);`, but in the drag/zoom functions you use: `x(d.Week_Num);`, this is easily fixed enough. This gives us:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    margin2 = {top: 230, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#a54300","#ec983d", "#ecc43d", "#f9ec86","#cbe989"]);


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Udayshan07/320ea33bacc3e04f9bd77538007527a0/raw/06e65434349e63ed6cf85c4d3e9cb383e888010c/sp500.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Week_Num = parseTime(d.Week_Num);
  });

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Week_Num; });
  var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; }));
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
  var data = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);

  x.domain([xMin, new Date()]);
  y.domain([0, yMax]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain())
  z.domain(keys);
 
  var messages = focus.append("g");
    messages.selectAll("message")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })   
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Week_Num); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .attr("width", 15)
     .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 5;
            var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 5;
            tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
            tooltip.select("text").text(d[1]-d[0]);
        });

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis.ticks(10))
      .selectAll("text") 
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
 
  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2)
      .selectAll("text") 
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());

  
});

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  
  focus.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Week_Num); })
  
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; 
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  
  focus.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Week_Num); });
  
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}

var tooltip = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");
      
  tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);

  tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
    .zoom {
      cursor: move;
      fill: none;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
       
    .axis {
      stroke-width: 0.5px;
      stroke: #888;
      font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis > path {
      stroke: #888;
    }
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

*This question doesn't address the need for a clip path so I haven't included it in my answer, but there are a considerable number of questions on that topic that should help, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236115/7106086) from a couple days ago.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This works. I have also added a clip path which works fine. However, I have an other problem with the tool tip and brush co-existing. I would like to know if there is way to solve this issue/

Comment: @UdayaShankar, Can you describe the issue at all? It might be best to post a new question, but it could be something I missed in my answer, either way, a quick description would help (I can't see any conflict between zoom/drag in the snippet above, but I might not be replicating the problem correctly).

Comment: I have added tool tip to display the number of errors on the chart when we mouse over the bars. However, zoom/brush function catches all of the pointer events and we do not see the tool tip on hover. I would like know how we can make both brush and tool tip to be available at the same time.

Comment: This would be best asked as a new question given it is a substantial question in and of itself - if this answer solved the initial problem it's always appreciated to accept it. I'll start looking at ways to make zoom/drag and mouseover get along better. A new question also ensure new eyes see the issue.

Comment: The answer provided solves the initial issue i had. I will create a new question for the mouseover issue. Thanks @Andrew Reid.